# C# cannot override inherited member

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, radix

I'm learning C# from a book named Chegwidden Gladdis. I'm making the same program and same code as written in the book. but there is a problem. i can't override a method from a parent class. I had fully readed the book from the start of chapter, 5 times, everyhing is the same but I can't figure out why I can't can't override a method from a parent class. Here's the code from the base class PassFailActivity.cs

```
using System;
namespace ProtectedMembers
{
    public class PassFailActivity : GradedActivity2
    {
        private double minPassingScore; // Minimum passing score

        /// <summary>
        /// The constructor sets the minimum passing score
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mps">The minimum passing score.</param>
        public PassFailActivity(double mps)
        {
            minPassingScore = mps;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The GetGrade method returns a letter grade determined
        /// from the score field. This methos overrides the base class method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The letter grade</returns>
        public override char GetGrade()
        {
            char letterGrade;

            if (base.GetScore() >= minPassingScore)
                letterGrade = 'P';
            else
                letterGrade = 'F';

            return letterGrade;
        }
    }
}
```

and GradedActivity2.cs

```
using System;

namespace ProtectedMembers
{
    public class GradedActivity2
    {
        protected double score; // Numberic score

        /// <summary>
        /// The SetScore method sets the score field.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">The value to store in score</param>
        public void SetScore(double s)
        {
            score = s;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The GetScore method returns the score.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The value stored in the score field</returns>
        public double GetScore()
        {
            return score;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The GetGrade method returns a letter grade determined from the score field.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Return the letter grade</returns>
        public char GetGrade()
        {
            char letterGrade;

            if (score >= 90)
                letterGrade = 'A';
            else if (score >= 80)
                letterGrade = 'B';
            else if (score >= 70)
                letterGrade = 'C';
            else if (score >= 60)
                letterGrade = 'D';
            else
                letterGrade = 'F';

            return letterGrade;
        }
    }
}
```

and PassFailExam

```
using System;

namespace ProtectedMembers
{
    public class PassFailExam : PassFailActivity
    {
        private int numQuestions; // Number of questions
        private double pointsEach; // Points for each question
        private int numMissed; // Number of questions missed

        /// <summary>
        /// The constructor sets the number of questions, the number
        /// of questions missed, and the minimum passing score.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="questions">The number of questions</param>
        /// <param name="missed">The number of questions missed</param>
        /// <param name="minPassing">The minimum passing score</param>
        public PassFailExam(int questions, int missed, double minPassing) : base(minPassing)
        {
            // Declare a local variable for the score.
            double numericScore;

            // Set the numQuestions and numMissed fields.
            numQuestions = questions;
            numMissed = missed;

            // Calculate the points for each questions and the numeric score for this exam.
            pointsEach = 100.0 / questions;
            numericScore = 100.0 - (missed * pointsEach);

            // Call the base class's SetScore method to set the mumeric score.
            SetScore(numericScore);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The GetpointsEach method returns the number of points each questions is worth
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The value in the pointsEach field</returns>
        public double GetPointsEach()
        {
            return pointsEach;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The GetNumMissed method returns the number of questions missed
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The value in the numMissed field</returns>
        public int GetNumMissed()
        {
            return numMissed;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Main

```
using System;

namespace ProtectedMembers
{
    public class PassFailExamDemo
    {
        public static void Main111()
        {
            int questions, // Number of questions
                missed; // Number of questions missed
            double minPassing; // Minmum passing score

            // Get the number of questions on the exam
            Console.Write("How many questions are " + "on the exam? ");
            questions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Get the number of questions missed.
            Console.Write("How many questions did " + "the student miss? ");
            missed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Get the minimum passing score
            Console.Write("What is the minimum " + "passing score? ");
            minPassing = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Create a PassFailExam project
            PassFailExam exam = new PassFailExam(questions, missed, minPassing);

            // Display the teset results.
            Console.WriteLine("Each questions counts {0} points.",
                exam.GetPointsEach());
            Console.WriteLine("The exam score is {0} ",
                exam.GetScore());
            Console.WriteLine("The exam grade is {0} ",
                exam.GetGrade());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

the output should be

```
How many questions are on the exam? 100
How many questions did the student miss? 25
What is the minimum passing score? 60
Each question counts 1 points.
The exam score is 75
The exam grade is P
```

I have tried to make the base method virtual and calling override when trying to override it and that just gets me this error "'ProtectedMembers.PassFailActivity.GetGrade()': cannot override inherited member 'ProtectedMembers.GradedActivity2.GetGrade()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override". i fully checked

Comment: You need to make `GetGrade` virtual in the root class of the inheritance tree.

Comment: You need to try to only include the code that is relevant to your question, you appear to have included all the code you have which makes it hard to determine where the issue lies

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option is to mark the function [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) in `GradedActivity2`:

```
public virtual char GetGrade()
```

From MSDN:

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or
> event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived
> class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that
> inherits it:

Comment: Thanks. sorry i did not search it on MSDN

Comment: Apparently I can't say "+1 for `The error is self-explanatory`"

Comment: If you understand the keyword Virtual you will not day error is not self explanatory, it is indeed

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx for anybody who wants quick reference

Comment: If the error was self-explanatory, prouser135 would not have asked the question and I would not have to Google it.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `GetGrade` in the base class should tell it allows to be derived, using the [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) keyword:

```
public virtual char GetGrade()
```

This is just a fail safe mechanism, and a opimization, since non-virtual methods don't have to be checked on derived methods in deriving classes.

Comment: OH FSCK, this is like in Turbo Pascal, quite the backstep from Java™ thus ☹ and *very* annoying if you need to override system behaviour…