# Polymorphism in C#. Base Class's Method is Called But Why?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

Most of the articles I read about Polymorphism of methods in an inheritance hierarchy **does not provide a reason** why this happens. Can someone please provide a reason or analogy of the following behavior?

```
Class A{
    public void Print(){
        Console.WriteLine("A.Print");
    }
}

Class B : A{
    public void Print(){
        Console.WriteLine("B.Print");
    }
}

Class Test{
   public static void Main(string[] args){
         A a = new B();
         a.Print();  // Prints "A.Print"
    }
}
```

The code in the Test class prints "A.Print", **But Why?**

Comment: `console.printline()`, Nice one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27500560/3901618

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1445/Introduction-to-inheritance-polymorphism-in-C

Comment: Thanks Toumash for the good code. Moderators, could you please remove the duplicate tag for this question. The new title I believe exactly focuses the topic which is not explicitly asked or answered.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an instance of B that is lets say "Bigger", but the variable 'a' is converted into class A that is "Smaller" and contains the method print A. You did something similar to:

A : IClass
B : IClass

The interface exposes some method that is in both A and B, and you to trigger it, use:

(IClass)A.Print
(IClass)B.Print

**The same is here:**

In simple words. B contains class A. So you with A a = new B(); Initiated the B class but in the same time extracted ( converted ) into A class.

Comment: I believe this is what I wanted (particularly the paragraph that concludes) or what I understand after reading further .. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In the class test you define an instance of type A
So the method Print from the definition of class A is called.

It has all to do with casting, maybe this is useful

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: By Implicit Conversion, I would conclude or assume - when I assign an instance of a derived class to an object of its base class's type, the derived class's instance is (implicitly) type converted into an object of the base class's type. I was also able to assure this - when i hovered over a member of the implicitly type converted object, it was showing up as the Base class's member. <br/> Thanks Cheese I marked yours as the answer, because it pretty much explains how i wanted to understand this. <br/> Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Make the base class method virtual and use override keyword in derived class method.